# Wrong result when copying an array of strings

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I have the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
char* user;
char* passwd;
int nr;

void test()
{
    int i=0;
    for(i=0;i<argc;i++)
    printf("Hello %s \n",user);
}

int main(int argc,char*argv[])
{
    int i;
    nr=argc;
    for (i=0; i<argc; i++)
    {
        user=strdup(argv[i]);

    }

    test();
return 0;
}
```

The result is the `argv[argc]` on all the positions. How can I fix this? I wwant to have that test() outside the loop.

**

> *EDIT*

**
After the ANSWERS here this is my new code, which is not working. Can anyone say why?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
char* user;


void test(int n)
{
    int i=0;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    printf("%s \n",user[i]);
}
int main(int argc,char*argv[])
{
     user = (char*) malloc(argc*sizeof(char));
int i;
for (i=0;i<argc;i++)
{
user[i]=argv[i];
}
test(argc);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Re edit: You need `malloc(argc*sizeof(char*))`. You want an array of `char*`, but forgot the `*` in the `sizeof` argument. And you must declare `user` as a `char**`.

Comment: why do I neec char* and char**?! can you please explain? I am confused

Comment: `argv[i]` is a pointer to `char`. You (try to) assign that to `user[i]`, for that to work, `user[i]` must be compatible with `char*`, so user should be either an array of `char*` - like `char *user[100];` if the size is known beforehand - or a pointer to a block of memory _used_ as an array of `char*`. The type of thing that `user` points to must then have the size of a `char*` for the indexing to work properly. The things pointed to by user must have the size of `char*`, and they're used as `char*`, so the proper thing is to declare them as `char*`, and `user` as a pointer to `char*`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you overwrite the pointers `user` and `passwd` in every iteration. Hence, you'll only see the last string.

If you can tell your aim of the program, a better answer can be provided. Because I am not sure whether you want to read one `user` and `passwd` Or an array of users and passwds.

After you edit, I see you want to read an array of strings:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
char** user;
// or char *user[100]; /* If you want a fix length array of pointers. Now, you dont have to malloc. /*
char* passwd;
int nr;

void test(int argc)
{
    int i=0;
    for(i=0;i<argc;i++)
    printf("Hello %s \n",user[i]);
}

int main(int argc,char*argv[])
{
    int i;
    nr=argc;
    user = malloc(argc*sizeof(char*));

    for (i=0; i<argc; i++)
    {
        user[i]=strdup(argv[i]);

    }
    test(argc);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: @justAngela see my edit now. Note that `argc` is not visible in `test()` and your code won't compile due to that.

Comment: i ve also edit my post, but mine is not working case I use char* instead of char**. Can you tell me why do YOU USE CHAR** instead of char* when initializing the array? THank you

Comment: `char*` is just pointer to a char, meaning you can only store one null-terminated string. Whereas `char**` is to store an array of strings which is what you want here.

Comment: also why didn t you add malloc(argc*sizeof(char*))? Can you please explan? THANK YOU VERY MUCH!

Comment: I edited. You can use either malloc or a fixed length like `char *user[100];`

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning to both password and user at each iteration of the for loop. The final values you see are from the last iteration. Also, there is memory leak due to overwriting the pointers from previous `strdup` calls. In fact, you do not need a loop:

```
int main(int argc,char*argv[])
{
  if(argc == 3) {
    user=strdup(argv[1]);
    passwd=strdup(argv[2]);
  } else {
    // error: usage
  }
  test();
  return 0;
}
```

If you want to have multiple user/password combinations:

```
char *user[256], *passwd[256]; 

void test(int n) {
  int i;
  for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    printf("Hello %s \n",user[i]);
}

int main(int argc,char*argv[])
{
  int i;
  for(i = 0; i < argc && i < 256; i+=2) {
    user[i]=strdup(argv[i]);
    passwd[i]=strdup(argv[i+1]);
  } 
  test(argc);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: perhaps you need another for, not this one.

Comment: I ve also edited my code. I don t know the array dimmension so I am using a dynamic array. Can you please tell me what am I doing wrong in the code I ve post under EDIT? PLEASE?

Answer (score 0):

Of course; in test() you don't use i other than a loop variable and in main() you keep overwriting the previous value of user and passwd. In effect, what you do is:

```
user   = strdup(argv[0]);  /* Note: argv[0] is the program name. */
passwd = strdup(argv[0]);
user   = strdup(argv[1]);
passwd = strdup(argv[1]);
user   = strdup(argv[2]);
passwd = strdup(argv[2]);
user   = strdup(argv[3]);
passwd = strdup(argv[3]);
printf("%s %s \n", user, passwd);
```

With this information, can you fix your program?

Comment: i see. so i need an array of users and passwords,no? I ve edited my code. Can you help me to solve it,please?

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to do. Please specify an example of the program invocation with arguments, and what you expect the output to look like exactly.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat trash.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void test(FILE* stream, char* usr, char* pass) {
    fprintf( stream, "%s@%s\n", usr, pass);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    int i = 1;
    if (argc % 2) {

        while(argv[i]) {

            test(stdout, argv[i], argv[i + 1]);
            i += 2;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

$ clang trash.c
$ ./a.out user1 pass1 user2 pass2
user1@pass1
user2@pass2
$
```

also if you call `strdup()` don't forget to free memory, because strdup called `malloc()`.